# Python SAT with pycosat

Tags: python

I have a class assignment in which I need to write a function that tests for SAT using the pycosat library.  I'm having difficulty trying to figure out a set of parameters that would return "UNSAT" from the library.  Can someone please help me find a set of parameters that are not "solvable"?  Looking over the unit tests for the library, the only instance I can find is [[1], [-1]]

**The assignment is much more complex, and I'm only looking to understand the SAT solver that is used to test my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:  You need to create a contradiction.  Create 3 variables (A, B, C).  In order to create an unsolvable computation you need to create a boolean operation that makes it impossible to solve.

(A or B) AND (Not A or Not B) AND (B or C)  AND (Not B or C)

A truth table would show that no combination of values of A, B or C could result in the above computation being true.  To represent this for pycosat it would look like:

[[1, 2], [-1, -2], [2, 3], [-2, 3]]